# One form, two submit buttons

Tags: forms, fancybox

I have one form and two submit buttons. at the moment they are like this:

What i would like to do is that the first submit buttons open in some nice popup window, like http://fancybox.net/

Any ideas?

Comment: What I assume should be your example code wasn't included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up your fancybox to open a window for a specific class:

```
$("#fancyButton").fancybox({
autoDimensions:true,
    titlePosition:'inside'
});
```

the first button would look like this:

```
<input type="button" id="fancyButton" value="button 1" />
```

Then have your second button the ACTUAL submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="button 2" />
```

Also, if you wanted the form data in the fancy box, use jQuery to scrap the relevant info and drop it in the box :)

To scrape the form:

```
var formData=new Array();
$('input').each(function(index) {   
    formData[$(this).name] =    $(this).value(); 
});
```

Call the above in a `$('#fancyButton').click()` function..

then you can reference each field by going `formData['`insert field name here`']`

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do it. I have a php file with a function where submit goes. I would like to show that in the fancy boy. So how do i do that (use jQuery to scrap the relevant info and drop it in the box)